# Getting "Can't add account from settings" error when adding Office account in Nokia X

Tags: ms-office

I am trying to add my `MS Office` account in `Nokia X` by going to:

> Settings --> Add account --> Office

but it shows `Can't add account from settings` error.

Can anyone has idea why does this error occur and what is its solution? Or is there any other way to add Office account?